# OS X Yosemite gcc unrecognized command line option 'mdll' after brew install gcc

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I installed gcc using brew because I needed to install brew's Fortran package. It seems that the gcc package installed by `brew install gcc` does not support the `mdll` flag. How can I install the correct versions of Fortran and gcc?

```
$ which gcc
/usr/local/bin/gcc

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.9.2 20141029 (prerelease)
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ gcc -mdll
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mdll’
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: what brew Fortran package? `gfortran` is now just part of gcc. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/28855

Comment: yes I installed gfortran through the brew gcc package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `gcc(1)` manpage:

```
-mdll
  This option is available for Cygwin and MinGW targets. It
  specifies that a DLL---a dynamic link library---is to be generated,
  enabling the selection of the required runtime startup object and
  entry point.
```

Since OS X isn't either Cygwin or MinGW, it's safe to assume that no version of GCC will enable it on OS X.

If you're trying to build a dynamically linked object ("shared object" in UNIX terminology), check out the `-dynamic`/`-dynamiclib` flags. They seem to be the rough equivalent on OS X.